# R: Append factor to empty vector and preserving factor values

Tags: r

I transformed my original problem into this toy problem:

I have this:

```
x <- c()
rep(time_factor[1], 3)
[1] [0,1) [0,1) [0,1)
Levels: [0,1) [1,15) [15,30) [30,40) [40,60]
```

But when I do `append`, I couldn't get the factors in the form of "[0,1)" . How can I solve this problem ?

```
append(x, rep(time_factor[1],3))
[1] 1 1 1
```

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't use `append` at all. However, you can use `append(x, as.character(rep(time_factor[1],3)))`.

Comment: Why not using `c(x, rep(time_factor[1],3))`

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `append` doesn't work for factors is that the underlying function `c` does not have a method for `factors`. So why not make your own? The method below is a possibility which seems to work for your case. Not sure if it works for all possible cases where you want to combine factors.

```
# reproducible example
time_factor <- cut(.5, c(0,1,15, 30, 40, 60), right=FALSE)
x <- c()
#
# original version
c(time_factor[1], time_factor[1])
  # [1] 1 1
append(x, rep(time_factor[1], 3))
  # [1] 1 1 1
#
# c method for factors
c.factor <-  function(...){
  y <- do.call(c, lapply(list(...), as.character))
  factor(y, unique(unlist(lapply(list(...), levels))))
}
#
# same as before with c.factor in global environment
c(time_factor[1], time_factor[1])
  # [1] [0,1) [0,1)
  # Levels: [0,1) [1,15) [15,30) [30,40) [40,60)
append(x, rep(time_factor[1], 3))
  # [1] [0,1) [0,1) [0,1)
  # Levels: [0,1) [1,15) [15,30) [30,40) [40,60)
```