# R: fail to convert factor to numeric

Tags: r

I have this factor vector:

`yoyo <- structure(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
+ 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("[0,1)", "[1,15)", "[15,30)", 
+ "[30,40)", "[40,60]"), class = "factor")`

When I tried to convert this factor vector to a numeric vector by

```
as.numeric(levels(yoyo)[yoyo])
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 

as.numeric(levels(yoyo))[yoyo]
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

I only get `NAs`. How can I solve this problem ?

**UPDATE:**
The question is how would one convert factors (obtained from `cut` function in R) to numeric values ? This is not something that is very easy or straightforward. So, I don't understand why this question is being downvoted.

And `as.numeric(yoyo)` is incorrect, as dictated in `?factor`.

Comment: Just `as.numeric(yoyo)`?

Comment: @nicola, no no **NO** . This is one of the classic errors.  Factors are numeric, but almost always what the user wants is the **labels** of the factors, so you must do `as.numeric(as.character(factors))` . This is in the R-FAQ.

Comment: what are you saying? He wants to coerce to a numeric, it doesn't seems that he wants the labels. Plus, your line only produces NA.

Comment: You have results from `cut` here. Each entry/level has two values, eg.,  `"[0,1)"`, What exactly you want to convert to `numeric`?

Comment: I still don't get what @CarlWitthoft was trying to say. OP has a factor vector and wants to coerce it to numeric. Maybe you thought that the levels of this factor can be coercible to numeric, but they aren't in this case. So your comment is waaaaayyyy off.

Comment: Related post(?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846998/r-append-factor-to-empty-vector-and-preserving-factor-values

Comment: see last example in `?cut`

Comment: having said that, and tried, it doesn't work on your example. Someone should improve those regex and suggest a change to R-devel.

Comment: @nicola  Yep, you're probably correct that he wanted for some strange reason to extract just the factor levels' numeric designations. But surprise ( :-( )  that's not what comes out of `as.numeric(levels)` anyway.  So maybe he wants something like `which((yoyo)==levels(yoyo)[1])`

Comment: I noticed that no one, not even the answerers, showed what the result is or should be.  What is the desired result?

Comment: Question is: how to transform the given factor vector into numeric values, as `as.numeric(yoyo)` is an incorrect way to do this ? There must be a way to do this in R.

Answer (score 2):

To get lower and upper limits of your levels, you can use

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(yoyo), split=','), 
       function(x) as.numeric(gsub(x, pattern="[^0-9]+", replacement="")))
```

Answer (score 1):

To get lower and upper limits, another way is:

```
library(stringr)
read.table(text=str_trim(gsub("[^0-9]+", " ", yoyo)),sep="")
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you're after is the first   `c(1L, 3L,....)` sequence you used to create `yoyo`,
then (EDIT)  `as.numeric(yoyo)` is all that's needed.

EDIT - I was doing it the hard way below.  Don't do what I did.

```
newstring <- rep(NA,length(yoyo))
(for j in 1:(length(levels(yoyo))) {
   indx <- which((yoyo)==levels(yoyo)[j])
   newstring[c(indx)] <- j
}
```

Comment: WHY? How does this differ from `as.numeric(yoyo)`? `identical(newstring, as.integer(yoyo))` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: @Shadow, my apologies -- you are correct.  I got sucked into a maelstrom of variants on `as.numeric(levels)` and didn't pay attention.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the class of your vector from `factor` to `numeric` (as I think you are asking) a simple `as.numeric` or `c` will suffice. If you want to have a numeric value which in some way represent the interval which is associated (your factor vector is very likely the output of the `cut` function), you should specify which value you want (since your levels specify a range, and not a single value). I propose a method to display the mean of every interval. A `[0,1)` value is replaced by 0.5, for instance.

```
    require(stringr)
    colMeans(matrix(as.numeric(simplify2array(str_extract_all(levels(yoyo),"[0-9]+"))),nrow=2))[yoyo]
```

Comment: If would be better to use the `labels` parameter of `cut` instead of jumping through these hoops.